# Vuetify: Adaptive v-date-picker width v-dialog and v-menu

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to do adaptive `v-date-picker`, i.e when phone page width then date picker open in `v-dialog`, and when desktop then data picker open in `v-menu`.

It's my try:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly">
      <v-dialog
        ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal"
        persistent
        width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <slot name="input" ref="input" v-on="on"/>
        </template>
        <slot name="picker" ref="picker"/>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        min-width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <slot name="input" ref="input" v-on="on"/>
        </template>
        <slot name="picker" ref="picker"/>
      </v-menu>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "v-date",
        data() {
            return {
                menu: false,
                modal: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.menu = false;
                this.modal = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But `v-on` doesn't work. I try `:listeners="on"`, it doesn't work too...

For example use component:

```
<v-date>
  <template v-slot:input>
    <v-text-field
      label="Дедлайн"
      v-model="data.deadline"
      readonly
    />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:picker>
    <v-date-picker v-model="data.deadline" no-title scrollable>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.deadline.close()">ОК</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </template>
</v-date>
```

Comment: Looking here: https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/dialogs/
There is <v-btn /> inside every  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">...</template>.
As far as i understand, you are trying to use <v-text-field /> instead of <v-btn/>. Maybe this causes problem?

Comment: @KrasnokutskiyEA, no. Look here https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/date-pickers/#date-pickers-in-dialog-and-menu

Comment: Ok, did you try to insert <v-text-field /> with v-on="on"  inside <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">..</template> instead of using <slot />? In docs they have  v-on="on" "attached" directly to <v-text-field />

Comment: @KrasnokutskiyEA cool, it's work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [KrasnokutskiyEA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419297/krasnokutskiyea) for the idea.

Work version:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly">
      <v-dialog
        ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal"
        persistent
        width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <slot name="input" ref="input" :on="on"/>
        </template>
        <slot name="picker" ref="picker"/>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        min-width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <slot name="input" ref="input" :on="on"/>
        </template>
        <slot name="picker" ref="picker"/>
      </v-menu>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "v-date",
        data() {
            return {
                menu: false,
                modal: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.menu = false;
                this.modal = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Use:

```
<v-date>
  <template v-slot:input="{ on }">
    <v-text-field
      label="Дедлайн"
      v-model="data.deadline"
      readonly
      v-on="on"
    />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:picker>
    <v-date-picker v-model="data.deadline" no-title scrollable>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.deadline.close()">ОК</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </template>
</v-date>
```